# How can I email the contents and URL of a blog post to someone with one click?

Tags: firefox

Assuming the blog itself doesn't have a share button, or perhaps even a blog at all.  Is there an easy way?  A special firefox bookmark that I can install?

Comment: I refuse to answer people who have never voted and never accepted an answer.

Comment: Or at least upvote good and useful questions and answers you come across.

Comment: You guys bored or something? He/She doesn't need to do anything. Seems to me like you are some sort of point chasers. A la "Accept Answers/Upvote to give me points, kplx?"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it has an RSS feed, you can subscribe to it in google reader and email it from there in one click but it only works on RSS feeds. 
Also, this isn't one click but if you install the clipmarks addon for firefox, you can click the button on the window and select what you want to send. https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1407

Comment: Google Reader is awesome for sharing items as you see them.  I send/forward items to people all the time using it.  Another plus is not having to look at so many hideous Blogger and WordPress themes.

Comment: Yes. No themes but it does work well for that. Use it with netnewswire and it is amazing.

Answer (score 1):

Click on `File -> Send Link` to send the link as an email.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the Ubiquity add-on (https://mozillalabs.com/ubiquity/).  It can do what you need, and much much more.